# The anti-forgery cookie token and form field token do not match

Tags: asp.net-mvc, forms-authentication

I have an ASP.Net MVC web app running in production, using Forms Authentication.  Every once in a while, I get the following error coming up when a user tries to log on:

> System.Web.Mvc.HttpAntiForgeryException (0x80004005): The anti-forgery
>   cookie token and form field token do not match.    at
>   System.Web.Helpers.AntiXsrf.TokenValidator.ValidateTokens(HttpContextBase
>   httpContext, IIdentity identity, AntiForgeryToken sessionToken,
>   AntiForgeryToken fieldToken)    at
>   System.Web.Helpers.AntiXsrf.AntiForgeryWorker.Validate(HttpContextBase
>   httpContext)    at
>   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeAuthorizationFilters(ControllerContext
>   controllerContext, IList`1 filters, ActionDescriptor actionDescriptor)
>   at
>   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.<>c__DisplayClass21.b__19(AsyncCallback
>   asyncCallback, Object asyncState)

The user tries a couple of times, then closes the browser and navigates back to the app and tries logging in again, and it then works.

I've been trying, but I am just unable to replicate this problem so that I can get to the bottom of it.  I thought maybe the user is bookmarking the logon screen, and that somehow the browser is caching an "old" token with that bookmark.  But I've tried this approach as well, and navigating to a bookmarked logon screen works fine in our tests.

I've found some questions that could possibly make the problem go away, but if I can't replicate the problem in development, I can't know that any of those suggested fixes works.

Any ideas on what a root cause may be for me to try replicate?

Comment: Can you reproduce your issue when you submit your form multiple times? (e.g. double click the login button)